# How to migrate a Linux KVM guest disk to another partition?

Tags: linux, kvm-virtualization

I've invested in some SSD drives and want to run my Linux KVM guests from them (currently on a SATA array). The current location of the guests is `/var/lib/libvirt/images`. I have the SSD volume mounted on `/mnt/ssd/`. The VMs do some calendaring and mail stuff and would rather not power them off to just use a simple copy command while they're cold. How can I move my KVM guests to the `/mnt/ssd/images/` directory and update the XML config for KVM? Found a similar question here ([How to migrate a running KVM (with full disk copy) to another node?](https://serverfault.com/questions/233992/how-to-migrate-a-running-kvm-with-full-disk-copy-to-another-node)) but it involves moving a guest to another server - I just want to change the directory and move the image.

Comment: Could you provide you information how you are mounting /var/lib/libvirt/images? If you are using LVM logical volumes, you will be able to move the data to SSD without disruption.

Comment: This is how the libvirt directory is mounted: `/dev/mapper/areca-libvirt on /var/lib/libvirt type ext4 (rw,noatime,nodiratime,data=ordered)`. It would be helpful to know if there's a way to move the physical image "hot" regardless of LVM. Sometimes I put slower VMs on the SATA partition to save the SSD volume for more intense services or  move images around if I have to rebuild/expand an array.